# What command lines correspond the UI elements of the GitHub Mac client?

Tags: git, github-for-mac

Each of the command buttons and controls in the user interface of the new [GitHub client for OS X](http://mac.github.com/) performs some basic `git` operation that can be performed on the command line as well. Is there a reference somewhere that lists what these commands are for each UI element; is there a way to see or observe what commands the app is executing?

Comment: Isn't this more a question for the GitHub support?

Comment: In case of git your approach should be the opposite - get familiar with the command line first and then correlate it with the GUI tool that you use.

Comment: @manojlds: Yes, that's the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read some info about Git like [progit.org](http://progit.org) (Awesome free book by Scott Chacon of GitHub) to learn the command line interface.

There's plenty of stuff that git can do, that is not in the GitHub client

Comment: I think he was asking about the _way to see the result of UI elements when pressed show up in commandline_ So that it will be easier in learning the commands. Though I agree **Pro Git** is very good book.

Comment: Great resource! Thanks. I'm more interested though in the *mapping* between the client app and the command line: which buttons and menus do what?

Comment: I remember seeing something in the post like "i am new to git" ... But I might have been wrong there. Sorry.

Comment: Does **SmartGit** satisfy his needs? I am not sure though correct me If I am wrong. +1 for ProGit :)

Comment: I do not think that they translate it to command line actions. I guess they use their own wrapper library around git: libgit2/objective-git: https://github.com/libgit2 ... But I think I haven't seen anything in the UI that wasn't covered in Scotts book